# how do i tell the android launcher to reload its icons?

Tags: android

while testing, if i load a new version of my application onto my phone, the icon shown in the launcher isn't refreshed.  is there any way to tell the launcher to reload its icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go into "Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications", on the nexus one at least, you have to go into the menu and "Filter" and then change to "All".  the htc evo 4g defaulted to "All".  Then select "Launcher" (at least if you're on stock android) and "click" the "Force stop" button.  the launcher then automatically restarts when you go back to the home screen.  functional brute force approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the adb tool (command line) you can try: `adb uninstall com.example.package` and then load it onto your phone again.

Answer (score 0):

the easy answer is... in your project, select your drawable folder, hit F5 to refresh all the drawables, then send a new build to the phone.

if it doesnt work the first time, change some code to let it know it needs to rebuild some stuff, then send it to the emulator again.